# disable 'font-style: italic' if element contains non-latin characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using JavaScript, how to find every element that have `font-style: italic` (in addition to `<i>` and `<em>`), and switch it to `font-style: normal` if the element contains one of more characters that are not Latin characters (`[a-zA-Z]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('selector_for_text_containers').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('style').replace('italic', 'normal');
    $(this).attr('style', str);
});
```

Comment: Can you make it more specific, so that it only affects elements that contain non-latin characters, eg `<i>Text άλφα</i>` and not `<i>Text</i>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method given from @Loyalty Technology in this function to test if the chars are available.

```
function validate() {

    var chars = 'άλφα';

    $.each( $('.text') , function (indx, elm) {

        var text = $(elm).text().split('');

        text.forEach( function( letter, ind ) {

            if ( chars.indexOf(letter) !== -1) {

                var str = $(this).attr('style').replace('italic', 'normal');

                $(elm).attr('style', str);

            }

        });

    });
```